# How to return this Multidimensional PHP Array as a JSON object?

Tags: php, javascript, json, model-view-controller

I have this code in my model when the controller requests to get all the messages for a certain user:

```
public function get_messages($user_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM messages 
            WHERE `to` = '$user_id'
            ORDER BY id DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);        
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'to' => $row->to,
            'from' => $row->from,
            'message' => $row->message,
            'star' => $row->star,               
            'timestamp' => $row->timestamp          
        );
    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Here's the code in my controller:

```
$result = $this->inbox_m->get_messages($user['id']);
```

How can I return the result as a JSON object using PHP's `json_encode()` function?

Normally I do something like this for simple returns:

```
json_encode(array('result' => true))
```

but all these arrays in arrays got me confused.

### EDIT

Never mind guys, should have actually tried it before posting. This works just fine:

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
```

I will close the question in a day when my account allows me.

Comment: **Warning** - your code is susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: @DanielA.White: The correct word is "susceptible". And there's no way of knowing whether it is or not. He could be cleaning the `$user_id` parameter before he ever calls that method.

Comment: fixed. but i'm just pointing it out.

Comment: @BryanRoss - I blame iPhone's autocorrect.

Comment: Thanks but I am sanitizing all user and get and post inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the question by answering it myself. Like explained in the edit this works just fine:

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode($messages);` should be fine here. Call it and examine the output to see if it's what you want. But `json_encode` should handle nested arrays without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Ha yeah realized it just after posting the question. Will remember to try it first next time before asking.